# how to parse each value of an array to the url one by one in jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter

I have a scenario

user logsin

through json path extractor i get all the reservation ids as an array

```
["75457052","75405285","75400251","75400246","75400252","75307496","75307497","75307498"]
```

Now user needs to navigate like /reservation/id to all the ids mentioned in the array

if in the response got from the above url ,certain criteria met ( as example say destinationCount > 1) then it would return that id and come out of the loop.

I need the first id which would meet the criteria

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if JSON path extractor exposes all matched values as variables, like regex does. You can use combination regex extractor and foreach controller, which will look like something as follows.

- Threadgroup

  - HTTP Sampler which will return reservation id

    - Regex post processor to match all matching reservation id
  - Bean shell processor to initialize destinationCount=0 and initialize the iterator i=1
  - foreach controller

    - ifcontroller (destinationCount < 1)
    - HTTP Sampler with ${reservation_id}_${i}

      - Beanshell processor to set the destinationCount to the new value

You may want to look at [these](http://my.kpoint.com/search?for=tag:regex_extractor) screen casts to see exactly how regex extractor and foreach controller are implemented.

Comment: I've already done with Regex and Foreach but I was looking how we can pass the each value of the output array from json path extractor to ForEach controller.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done is as below

```
Navigate to reservations to get all the reservation ids
Through regular expression extractor :-
    Reference Name :- getreservationid
    Regular expression:- "id": \"(.+?)\"
    Match No :- -1
    Template:- $1$

Then add foreach controller
  input variable prefix :- getreservationid
  output variable name :- reservationid

Then add http sampler to go to each reservationid :- /reservation/${reservationid}/home
 Add json path extractor :- Name - numberOfLocations, JSON path     :- $.payload.destinationGuide.numberOfLocations
   Then add if controller ${numberOfLocations} > '1'
      Then add the http sampler as example go to the weather page of that id :- /reservation /${reservationid}/weather
      //I need to go only once to that weather page and then come out of for each controller
      then add BSF post processor -> beanshell ( this is to remove all the variables so that it would come out from the foreach controller)
      copy = new HashSet(vars.entrySet());
         for (Iterator iter = copy.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
         e = iter.next();
         if ( e.getKey().startsWith("getreservationid") ) {
          vars.remove(e.getKey());
       }
     }
```